# How to bind typeahead enter event to a textbox in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typeahead.js

I want to bind `Typeahead` enter event in angularjs. I have always used `jQuery` as follows:

```
this.$("input#search-box").bind('typeahead:enterKeyed', function (e, data) {
    //to do stuff
}
```

I want write code similar to this in angularjs.I am using `ui-bootstrap-typeahead` typeahead is working fine but need to bind the enter event to load other functions

I have tried this:

```
angular.module('genericDirectives', []).directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("typeahead:enterKeyed", function (event) {
                    console.log("Enter");
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="selectedSongs" ng-enter="reloadData(selectedSongs)" typeahead="songs for songs in getSongs($viewValue)" class="form-control" />
```

P.S.: I am new to angualrjs

Comment: Your best bet is probably [`ui.bootstrap.typeahead`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: there is no bind event to it

Comment: tried that but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using: `typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label)`.

Example:

```
<input id="search-box" type="text" ng-model="selectedData" typeahead-on-select="doSomething(selectedData)" />
```

Make sure you have it in `$scope`:

```
$scope.doSomething = function (value) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: What a beaut.  Good suggestion!